# How to process python dictionary items in the order of value item?

Tags: python, json, sorting, dictionary

I get the following JSON from a web service. How to get an ordered collection from the following JSON in Python. I want to process key value pairs in the ascending order of "order" number.

```
{
  "key1": {
    "order": 10,
    "name": "somenameZ"
  },
  "key2": {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "somenameY"
  },
  "key3": {
    "order": 8,
    "name": "somenameX"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the `dict.items()` result with a custom key:

```
ordered = sorted(outerdict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['order'])
for key, item in ordered:
    # ...
```

If you only need the nested dictionaries, and not the outer keys, you could do the same for `dict.values()`:

```
ordered = sorted(outerdict.values(), key=lambda v: v['order'])
for item in ordered:
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I haven't used lambda before! Seems powerful. In kv: kv[1], what is 1 here?

Comment: @Nemo: each entry in the `dict.items()` sequence is a tuple with a key and a value; `kv[1]` picks the value (your nested dictionaries).